# MGWT ScrollPanel.scrollTo(0, y) leads to Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt, mgwt

I use the ScrollPanel from MGWT and do the following:

```
  private void scrollToBottom() {
    if (getUiHandlers().isVisible()) {
      final int height = scrollPanel.getOffsetHeight();
      final int heightInt = cellList.getOffsetHeight();
      final int y = scrollPanel.getMaxScrollY();

      if (heightInt >= height) {
          scrollPanel.scrollTo(0, y);
      }
    }
  }
```

When it comes to this line:

```
scrollPanel.scrollTo(0, y)
```

I get the following error:

```
UncaughtException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'style' of undefined 
UncaughtException details: setDelay_1_g$
UncaughtException details: setTransitionsDelay_0_g$ 
UncaughtException details: scrollbarPos_0_g$ 
UncaughtException details: pos_1_g$ 
UncaughtException details: execute_30_g$ 
UncaughtException details: startAnimation_0_g$ 
UncaughtException details: scrollTo_7_g$
UncaughtException details: scrollTo_6_g$
UncaughtException details: scrollTo_5_g$ 
UncaughtException details: scrollTo_3_g$
```

**How can I prevent this error?**

Comment: Did you call scrollTo before the ScrollPanel is added to the DOM? See my updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35016359/1417396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code and your stack trace it looks like you've experiencing issues with the scrollbar. Does your mgwt scrollpanel always has a scroll when you call scrollTo?

Also, I highly recommend you to wrap the `scrollPanel.scrollTo(0, y);` call into `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeffered(..your scrollTo call here`enter code here`..)`

Comment: It does not always has a scroll bar. Why do you use the scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you call either setScrollingEnabledY(true) or setShowVerticalScrollBar(true) or setShowScrollBarY(true).

And none of them with (false).

2) The scrollbar is only initialised upon a scrollPanel.refresh() call, which is also called **asynchronously** in onAttach() when the ScrollPanel is attached to the DOM.

2a) So make sure you do **not** call scrollTo **before** the ScrollPanel is added to the DOM (shown).

2b) **And** wrap the scrollTo call in a timer.schedule(1) to address the asynchronously call in onAttach().

Comment: I did ``scrollPanel.setScrollingEnabledX(false);
    scrollPanel.setShowHorizontalScrollBar(false);
    scrollPanel.setShowVerticalScrollBar(true);
    scrollPanel.setBounce(false);
    scrollPanel.setHideScrollBar(false);`` in the View's constructor.